# Rails 4 ajax flash messages cause strange behaviour for non xhr requests

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a Rails4 application and it is serving flash messages to jQuery on ajax requests. This works fantastically. On Non-xhr requests however my code misbehaves, it doesn't display any flash message until the next ajax request.

On a redirect in the controller no flash message is displayed, but the next time any ajax request is made the outdated flash message appears.

Here is my code:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  respond_to :html
  after_action :flash_to_headers

private

  def flash_to_headers
    return unless request.xhr?
    response.headers['X-Message'] = flash_message
    response.headers["X-Message-Type"] = flash_type.to_s
    flash.discard # don't want the flash to appear when reloading the page
  end

  def flash_message
    [:error, :warning, :notice].each do |type|
      return flash[type] unless flash[type].blank?
    end
    # if we don't return the above code will give "error, warning, notice"
    return ''
  end

  def flash_type
    [:error, :warning, :notice].each do |type|
      return type unless flash[type].blank?
    end
  end

end


class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def destroy
    # Sign-out user...
    redirect_to sign_in_path, warning: "Signed out successfully"
  end

end
```

Coffeescript:

```
  $(document).ajaxComplete (e, request) ->
    message = request.getResponseHeader('X-Message')
    type = request.getResponseHeader('X-Message-Type')
    if message
      MyApp.FlashManager.open(message, type)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you put your flash messages on the page when a non-ajax request comes in? If you don't render flash messages on the page during the HTML rendering, flash will stay in the queue until you discard it with the next ajax request.

Comment: This really surprised me. I was midway building this functionality, it seems as long as I call flash[:notice] (or warning or whatever) somewhere Rails knows. Interesting.